# Could a near future version of assault sappers work?

Tags: warfare, near-future

These units would be a version of [the soviet assault sappers from WW2](https://community.battlefront.com/topic/136836-soviet-assault-engineers-elite-infantry-in-bodyarmor/), updated with near future technology. The equivalent to their steel breastplates would be light power armour. The flamethrowers would be replaced with thermobaric rocket launchers. They would a have a **very** ***very*** large amount of light unguided AT weapons like the Panzerfaust 3. They would have multiple large recoilless rifles in each platoon, either used by people in large suits of power armour or on light vehicles. They also would have flamethrower tanks. They can either be split up to support other units or used as one. Their role is to break through heavily defended areas & settlements. Could this work?

Comment: VTC:Needs Details. If the goal is to break up my nephew's soccer game, it'll work great. If the goal is to stop an incoming nuclear missile, they're useless. Asking if something (weapon, soldier, anything...) will "work" in a military context is meaningless if you're not going to provide the context. Militaries ancient and modern have a bazillion of specialized duties, each designed to overcome a specific problem. You've designed the specialized duty *without having any problem to overcome.* Are you asking us to invent the problems? (\*continued\*)

Comment: I bring this up to share an important lesson the V.P. of a company I once worked for taught me. After a couple of programmers and I had developed a proposal for what we thought was a cool new enhancement to the software we were developing, he pointed out, "this appears to be a solution in search of a problem." In other words, the proposed feature was super cool... and super useless. We abandoned it because we couldn't come up with a problem that couldn't be solved more cheaply using existing methods. You're in the same boat. What's the problem these guys are expected to solve?

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact Their role is to break through heavily defended areas & settlements, its the second to last sentence of the question.

Comment: But that means nothing. What does "heavily defended" mean? Thousands of troops? Thick walls? Laser satellites? A moat? Tanks? Artillery? Boy scouts? A well-funded police force? Built atop a mountain? Built next to a river? Population of 15? 1.5 million? Is the wall made of adobe? Stone? Metal? Laminate? *Needs details* means you need to provide a ***great deal more*** than a single, ambiguous sentence.

Answer (score 3):

**Sapper** is just a traditional name for **combat engineer.**

And combat engineers are traditionally used not just for the creation of obstacles but also for the breaching of obstaces. Doctrine differs a bit on just how up close and personal these specialized *low density assets* should go. Also, your proposed TO&E is rather reminiscent of the USMC assault platoons in WWII ([p. 91 of this](https://www.marines.mil/Portals/1/Publications/History%20of%20the%20U.S.%20Marine%20Corps%20in%20WWII%20Vol%20IV%20-%20Western%20Pacific%20Operations%20%20PCN%2019000262700_1.pdf) history for the weapons mix the Marines trained with). Meanwhile, Germany labeled the successors of their [stormtroopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormtroopers_(Imperial_Germany)) the storm engineers (briefly mentioned in the [German Wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pionier_(Milit%C3%A4r)#Einsatz_im_Zweiten_Weltkrieg)).

So the general answer is yes, there will be combat engineers. Possibly specialized for urban assault, possibly not.

- Traditional flamethrower tanks force the tank to expose itself to an uncomfortable degree, just as backpack flamethrowers expose the individuals who carry them. So probaby not.
- Recoilless rifles have been largely replaced by rockets and guided missiles. There are some cases where recoilless rifles find better ways of dealing with their backblast than rockets deal with their exhaust, but guidance packs get cheaper and better.
- The Panzerfaust concept tries to put a large punch into a lightweight, man-portable package, at the expense of the number of shots. Instead of many panzerfausts, should it be a multi-barrel and/or reloadable system? Perhaps a breech-loading mortar?

The general advice for workbuilding: Decide if you want to copy the look-and-feel or the essence of a historical unit. If you want to copy the look-and-feel, be prepared that you will have to twist your setting to *make* it happen. Take the worldbuilding by David Weber in the [Honorverse](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/HonorHarrington). He wanted *Hornblower in Space*, so he rigged his technobabble to get ships of the line.

Comment: Assault Sappers aren't just combat engineers. Within the soviet military they were an elite. They used different tactics & were expected to be able to operate independently from infantry. They had 2 infantry guns in each platoon, most of the time infantry guns were a regiment level thing. They had body armour in era were body armour was rare. They were in brigades vs the rest of the infantry that used divisions. They used very *very* large amounts of captured panzerfausts.

Comment: Also your link to german "storm engineers" doesn't mention anything about storm engineers (i ctrl +f'd it) & that page doesn't seem to have anything on "USMC assault platoons" going both by PDF page number & actual page number

Comment: @OT-64SKOT, the storntroopers link goes to stormtroopers. For *Sturmpioniere* I had a German link ready, not an English one. Do you think that would help? You are right re page numbers, I mean p. 91 as numbered in the book. Right column, center.

Comment: ye, the german link would help.